# Execute Bash command inside Python Script

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I have a python code in my local environment.

I also have another code in Python which run in a bash command in a virtual environment.

If I run "subprocess.call" inside my python script it will run the python shell which won't work.

How can I run the universe_deduplicate.py (my code in the virtual environment) in a bash command inside my python script?

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("C://Users...../dedupe/universe_deduplicate.py", shell=True)
```

Comment: can't you just import it?

Comment: *If I run "subprocess.call" inside my python script it will run the python shell which won't work.* Can you explain what you mean by this? `subprocess.call` does not execute scripts in the python shell.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. The code universe_duplicate needs to be run in a virtual environment. If I only want to run this code, I open my bash command and simply "python universe_deduplicate.py" and it runs. how I can make it run inside a python script

Comment: Also, can you explain what you mean by executing "in a bash command"? Do you just want the script to run, or do you specifically what to first start a bash shell then run the command through bash?

Comment: I want to call the bash shell and run my python script universe.deduplicate.py

Comment: Have you tried `subprocess.call("python .../universe_deduplicate.py", shell=True)`?

Comment: If I'm right the ''shell=True'' will run in a normal cmd command, not in bash so my code won't run

Comment: `If I'm right the ''shell=True'' will run in a normal cmd command, not in bash so my code won't run`. Did not understand this. The py script will be finally called by python executable. Do you want that python exe's parent (and environment) has to be `bash` and not `cmd`? Or do you want to use `python.exe` from `<cygwin/msys/bash_root>/usr/bin/python.exe` and not something like `C:\python27\python.exe`?

Comment: Correct in bash

Comment: Please explain why you *must* run through bash? If you can execute the script without bash, would that be acceptable? Because it seems odd to require that you first start a bash interpreter only to start the python interpreter. If you *must* use bash, try passing "bash -c 'python ......py'" to subprocess.

Comment: Im running in bash this library code https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe-examples which need to be in a virtual env. That's why it has to be in called in a 'bash shell'.... So if only run this code.. I will do: simon@DESKTOP-VVDUT7U:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/venv/...... /python universe_deduplicate.py

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.call(path\to\bash -c "python C://Users...../dedupe/universe_deduplicate.py", shell=True)
```

Should work for you.

Comment: Try many things... Cant figured out the syntax ... subprocess.call(mnt\c\WINDOWS\system32\bash -c "python C://Windows/System32/venv/dedupe-examples-master/csv_DEDUPE_UNIVERSE/universe_deduplicate.py", shell=True)

Comment: If you are using WSL use 'type -a bash' in your command line to get the path to bash.  It should just be subprocess.call(/bin/bash -c ... )